# How to change the condition to AND in accessing content by role in a view-block?

Tags: 8, views, blocks

I have a view-block 'Expo', I want to display this block only if current user has two specific user roles i.e., 'Actor' and 'Singer'.

[image]

When I checked the both 'Actor' and 'Singer' , The block is displaying in users who have either 'Actor' or 'Singer' user role. When the user has two user roles it's displaying two blocks.

As per my understanding, It's using conditional OR in between the checked user roles. How can I change it to conditional AND?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the [`Role`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Plugin%21views%21access%21Role.php/function/Role%3A%3Aaccess/8.2.x) access plugin is written in a way that its `access` method works effectively like an `OR`:

```
public function access(AccountInterface $account) {
  return array_intersect(array_filter($this->options['role']), $account->getRoles());
}
```

To change this behavior, you can do it in two ways:

- Creating a new `ViewsAccess` plugin that mostly works like `Role` but operates with an `AND`. To do this, extend the `Role` class, override the `access` method, and then declare this class as a new `@ViewsAccess` plugin (remember to give it a unique ID and a new name). This new plugin will show up beside the existing `Role` plugin.
- Alternatively, you can add an option on the existing `Role` plugin to make it behave like an `AND` when told to. To do this, you extend the existing `Role` class, override `buildOptionsForm` method to add the option, override the `access` method to only work like an `AND` if it's configured to, then [alter the existing `Role` plugin's class to point to your extended version](https://medium.com/@djphenaproxima/how-to-bend-drupal-8-plugins-to-your-nefarious-will-94da0c31f095) instead of the one from Views.

  - If you're familiar with working with form alters and view alters to modify forms and how things render based on the form values, this approach is almost similar.

Comment: How can I do the same with normal block which is not view block?

Comment: @SteveSiddu Remember the part in Block Layout where you limit a block's visibility by Role, Content Type, and/or Path? Those are [`@Condition` plugins](https://www.drupal.org/node/1961370). They're a different type of plugin but operates similar to (and just as overridable as) `@ViewAccess` plugins.